# ¿Es posible implementar una función que en C# Winforms que reorganice los elementos como Android?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, drag-and-drop

Tengo este menú (estilo Android), que está en un `FlowLayoutPanel`.

La función del `FlowLayoutPanel` es organizar los elementos (Bunifu Tile Buttons) de forma automática:

[image]

Bien, ya con esto, primero, decidí hacer uso del método estático `SetDraggable(Control)` de la clase `Drag` de mi biblioteca de clases `Hector Framework`

```
Hector.Framework.Utils.Drag.SetDraggable(bunifuTileButton1);
```

Bien, el problema aqui fue que al arrastrar los elementos, estos empezaban a parpadear rápidamente y al soltarlos, simplemente regresaban a su posición original, ya que el `FlowLayoutPanel` forza a los elementos a mantenerse en la posición inicial cuando se está en tiempo de ejecución.

Así que decidí desarrollar un bloque de código personalizado que se adaptase a lo que quiero implementar:

```
...

Interval = 100, Enabled = true;      

private void Timer_0_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      var cursor = Cursor.Position;
      if(bunifuTileButton1.DisplayRectangle.Contains(cursor))
      {
         if(Hector.Framework.Utils.Mouse.MouseButtonIsDown(Hector.MouseButton.Left))
         {
              bunifuTileButton1.Location = cursor;
         }
     }
}
```

Usé un `Timer` que constantemente ejecuta un bloque de código que detecta si el control contiene la posición del puntero...

```
bunifuTileButton1.DisplayRectangle.Contains(cursor)
```

Y que mientras el botón izquierdo del ratón no se suelte...

```
Hector.Framework.Utils.Mouse.MouseButtonIsDown(Hector.MouseButton.Left)
```

La posición del control será la misma que la del cursor.

Sin embargo, sigue ocurriendo lo mismo.

En tiempo de diseño, el `FlowLayoutPanel` permite reposicionar sus elementos y al mismo tiempo los ordena de forma automática.

¿Existe alguna forma de hacer esto también en tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: No se mucho de WinForm ¿pero puedes crear un contenedor interno en el FlowLayoutPanel ? algo así como cajas estáticas donde pueden estar tos controles.

Comment: @bercklynCarlosviza Gracias por la idea, pero, resulta que ya la implementé.
Para eso es necesario usar paneles, y los paneles también son controles, por lo que sería el mismo resultado

Comment: Usa los métodos y eventos del FlowLayout, mira este ejemplo: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48411/Using-the-FlowLayoutPanel-and-Reordering-with-Drag